# Colombian TP-13 Visa Category

Tags: working-visas, indian-citizens, colombia

I'm planning to go to Colombia, in search of work and live there as my girlfriend's from there, from what I searched, I think TP-13 is my best option. Can someone share his/her experience with the same?

Point's that my matter,

- I have worked in Colombia (TP-6) & Brazil for one year each before,
- I'm Indian but currently I'm in Canada, and I will be applying for the visa from here
- When I contacted the embassy for the visa documents they said I need to show funds in a local bank account approximately 1500 CAD/month for tourist visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the best way to get a TP-13 is via a company, without which the Embassy wont provide the TP-13 visa to show my expertise in my skill.

Comment: Please accept this as an answer.

Comment: This is not the best answer, that is why I have removed it from the accepted answer. I'm waiting for a response from the Embassy in the next 72 hours and will be updating this information here.